# How to use Map.Entry interface correctly, and why are Map.Entry's methods implemented already?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I am confused using Map.Entry interface.  I found an example, shown below, using Map.Entry, but it returns error if "implements Map.Entry" is added at the end of its class.  In addition, an interface shouldn't have its methods implemented, but there are 5 methods (equals, getKey, getValue, hashCode, setValue) implemented in this interface. Can  someone explain what's going on here?

Furthermore, based on Oracle's Java Tutorial, "If your class claims to implement an interface, all methods defined by that interface must appear in its source code before the class will successfully compile."  So I guess since the following example doesn't need to implement Map.Entry interface, there is no need to implement the 5 methods listed in Oracle's Java API.  But why?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.*;

class Dog {
    String color;

    Dog(String c)  color = c;
    public boolean equals(Object o) 
        return ((Dog) o).color.equals(this.color);  
    public int hashCode() 
        return color.length();
    public String toString()
        return color + " dog";  
}

public class TestHashMap {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Dog, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Dog, Integer>();
    Dog d1 = new Dog("red");
    Dog d2 = new Dog("black");
    Dog d3 = new Dog("white");
    Dog d4 = new Dog("white");

    hashMap.put(d1, 10);
    hashMap.put(d2, 15);
    hashMap.put(d3, 5);
    hashMap.put(d4, 20);

    //print size
    System.out.println(hashMap.size());

    //loop HashMap
    for (Map.Entry<Dog, Integer> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
      System.out.println(entry.getKey().toString() + " - "+      entry.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding "5 methods are already implemented"... google for Java 8 default methods. They're a fairly new feature.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're asking, but any `Map<K,V>` implementation most certainly implements an appropriate version of `Map.Entry<K,V>` internally. The reason it's defined as an interface rather than a class is to allow `Map` implementations to vary implementation details such as concurrency resistance and mutability, etc.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Also, what is your question? (apart from the "already implemented methods" thing)

Comment: My question is half solved, thanks you immibis.  Just to clarify.....there is no need to add "implements Map.Entry" to the end of a class name if I simply use its default methods, correct?

Answer (score 2):

A `Map.Entry` is a key-value pair, as returned in the view [Map.entrySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--). Your class `Dog` is being used as a key; it isn't, and doesn't need to be a `Map.Entry`. The implementation of `Map.Entry` is typically an implementation  detail of the `Map` itself. It is rare that you will need to implement one.